# Tag Video no Html não suporta no firefox e funciona no internet explore

Tags: html5, vídeo

Estou implementando modulo de videos no sistema da minha empresa, só que quero pegar um video do disco C: do servidor, para ser exibido dentro do sistema, mais no internet explore e edge funciona normal e até no browser do compliador do eclipse abre, mais no principal que é o firefox que preciso e nem no Chrome não funciona, alguma dica pessoal ? Codigo abaixo

Comment: Você está obtendo algum erro no console? Está especificando o caminho direto no arquivo "C:/..." ou está fazendo uma requisição http? Coloca seu html pra vermos o que você já testou

Comment: Não estou tendo nada no console. No browser, ele simplemente fala que o formato do video ou `mime` não são suportados, mas o estranho é que se eu chamo o video dentro do projeto funciona, mas pegando do `C:/` só funciona no **Internet Explorer** e **Edge**.